# Why is my program throwing seg-faults sometimes and consistently?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm implementing a class called BigNum designed to handle arbitrarily large numbers. The way I implemented it is with an array of unsigned integers, making it effectively a base-(2^32) number, with an int member for length.

I've gotten subtraction, multiplication, and all 6 comparison operators working, but the modulus function is sometimes throwing a segmentation fault.

The way my function works is by first, checking if other is at least half of "this" (the calling object). If it is, it merely subtracts other from this. If it's not,

I'm testing with a bigNum that's three ints long. The most significant is 1, the middle is 0, and the least significant is 415, so it's 1*2^64+0*2^32+415*2^0, which is 18446744073709552031. I used a loop to test my number modulo every number between 1 and 29. If the second operand is 5, 14, 15, 21, 23, or 26, it always throws a seg-fault. Otherwise, it never throws a seg-fault. I have not yet checked if the answers are right to the others.

I put cout statements on a series of lines to narrow down the seg-fault line, and it was the line "return result" (marked below). I also put the modulus statement alone in my testing (as opposed to using a cout) and it still threw the seg-fault, so I know it's not my outputting the number causing the seg-fault.

I'm calling the first function below that takes an unsigned long, which in turn converts the long to a BigNum, and then performs modulus on the two BigNums: the operation throwing the seg-fault.

Here are my functions

```
BigNum *BigNum::operator% (unsigned long number) { //converts the long to a BigNum, then performs modulus on two BigNums
    //dynamically allocated because the BigNum destructor requires it
    unsigned int *parts = new unsigned int [2];
    parts [0] = (int) number;
    parts [1] = (int) (number >> 32);
    BigNum *asBig = new BigNum (parts, 2);
    BigNum *result = *this % *asBig;
    delete asBig;
    asBig = NULL;
    return result;
}

BigNum *BigNum::operator% (BigNum& other) { //two BigNums. Does the actual modular work
    BigNum *result;
    BigNum *replica;
    BigNum *test;
    this->simplify(); //cuts off any leading zero ints
    other.simplify();
    if (*(*this - other) < other) { //if other is less than half of this
        result = new BigNum(this->numbers, this->length);
        while (*result > other) {
            result = *result - other;
        }
        return result; //line throwing seg-fault
    }
    //if other is significantly smaller than this, the O(n) solution above is inefficient
    else {
        replica = new BigNum (other.numbers, other.length);
        while (true) { //makes "replica" equal "other" times the highest power of two possible without exceeding "this"
            test = *replica * 2;
            if (*test > *this) {
                break;
            }
            replica = test;
        }
        replica = (*this) % (*replica); //replica is smaller than this, but replica%other == this%other
        return (*replica % other);
    }
}
```

Here are the prototypes for all the functions I called in there.

```
BigNum::BigNum (unsigned int*, int);
BigNum *BigNum::operator* (unsigned long);
BigNum *BigNum::operator- (BigNum&);
bool BigNum::operator< (BigNum&);
bool BigNum::operator> (BigNum&);
void BigNum::simplify();
```

I tried checking for rogue pointers, but didn't see any, and those would throw seg-faults a lot more frequently and less consistently. I found the idea of stack-corruption online, but that only seems to be causable by a rogue pointer.

I also tried dereferencing the pointer and cout-ing the value just before returning, and the cout worked (I still got a seg-fault though). Finally, I tried returning other BigNum pointers, and still got a seg-fault on the same numbers. Am I looking at a corrupted stack? If so, how would I fix it? If not, what would be causing my return statement to seg-fault?

Comment: Debugger, did you use a debugger?  If so, what was the last statement executed before the fault?

Comment: It will be more helpful to post a [mcve] instead of all the text. See [ask].

Comment: This concerns me: `result = new BigNum(this->numbers, this->length);` Now you have two `BigNum` objects that refer to the same dynamically-allocated array of numbers. If the `BigNum` destructor deletes the array, as implied in the comment, then one of them will have an invalid pointer when the other one is destructed.

Comment: Why do you have `operator*()`, `operator-()`, and `operator%()` returning a pointer?   They are all conventionally implemented to return by value.

Comment: My last comment, BTW, was not an idle question.   It is a hint about a potential contributor to the problem.   Essentially, your class design is broken, it is using pointers unnecessarily, and doing so in ways that make mistakes likely.   Hence there are multiple factors causing a crash, some of which (e.g. in constructors) you have not shown.   Giving a useful answer is therefore prohibitive - since, when one problem is fixed, another will emerge.   Hence my vote to close the question.

Comment: I see. The reason I went for that was it was that, copy the object in a return-by-value scenario, or a local variable on the heap in a return-by-reference scenario. Which would you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

@Barmar noticed that I was trying to use the same dynamically allocated array for two different numbers, and that I should change them. It was a fantastic idea, but it did not solve the issue.

It turns out that, for whatever reason, my block that started like

`if (*(*this - other) < other) {`

was working if the problem was something like 7%4, but not if it was 1%5 (the first operand had to be bigger, which it wasn't always was). The way I solved it was by adding a block before that checked if the first operand was already smaller.

Answer (score 0):

This comment:

```
//dynamically allocated because the BigNum destructor requires it
```

implies that the `BigNum` constructor simply sets the `numbers` member to the argument, and the destructor does `delete [] numbers`. But this means you should not have two `BigNum` objects with the same `numbers` pointer, because when one of them is destroyed, the other will have an invalid `numbers` pointer.

So these lines in the `%` operator are a problem:

```
    result = new BigNum(this->numbers, this->length);
    ...
    replica = new BigNum (other.numbers, other.length);
```

You need to make copies of `numbers` before you use them.

```
    unsigned int *newnumbers = new numbers[this->length];
    memcpy((void*)newnumbers, (void*)this->numbers, sizeof(unsigned int) * this->length);
    result = new BigNum(newnumbers, this->length);
```

It would probably be better to do this in the `BigNum` constructor, rather than requiring the caller to provide a dynamically-allocated array -- it's generally best to have responsibility for allocating and freeing memory in the same module.